# How much can be dangerous a '@class_object_instance.save!(:validate => false)' method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to know "*how much can be dangerous*" to use the following statement in order to save a record in the database:

```
@user.save!(:validate => false)
```

That is, what can happen? For example, can a malicious user to hack something (eg: set some not allowed value) in the database?

Notice: I am referring mostly to the `:validate => false` part of the above code that makes it possible to skip validation processes.

Comment: Well, the primary concern about skipping validation is that it will let users enter garbage data into your database.  If you ever find yourself needing to skip model validation, it's a sign that you need to update your validations.

If you skip validation, database strings will still be escaped, so you can't enter values like "'; drop table users;" into the DB.  Rails 3 also escapes html in strings by default, so unless you specifically say <%= string_value.html_safe %> then string_value will display with escaped HTML.  So you'll probably safe from hackers, but your data quality will suffer.

Answer (score 1):

Can a malicious user 'hack something'? That depends. `:validate => false` disables any validation logic in the class `@user` belongs to. If you've mass-assigned the parameters you wanted to update in the normal way, you still get all the escaping which will protect you from SQL injection type attacks.

However if the integrity of the application rests on something on `@user` being valid, you might be in trouble- think of users setting their own account balances, adding extra subscriptions for free, altering expiry dates etc...

I'm not sure what your application does. Look at the relevant validation logic, question why it's there, then ask yourself what would happen if it were disabled and something broke. In general `:validate => false` is not a good idea.